# Java WebStart doesn't load keystore

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jboss

I have a standalone application that is basically a WS client. It connects to a secure WS, which uses certificates to authenticate, deployed on JBoss AS7. Everything works fine (both keystore and truststore are loaded) when I launch the app from my IDE, but when I try as a **webstart** app comes the trouble.

The problem is that when launched from webstart, **keystore is not loaded**. On the other hand, the truststore loads perfectly. 
Webstart console output:

```
trustStore is: /home/matijav/certs/matija.truststore
trustStore type is : JKS
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=matija, OU=Dev, O=SL, L=Lj, ST=Slo, C=SI
Issuer:  CN=matija, OU=Dev, O=SL, L=Lj, ST=Slo, C=SI
Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x52b45d57
Valid from Fri Dec 20 16:08:07 CET 2013 until Thu Mar 20 16:08:07 CET 2014
```

Because of this, when my app tries to connect to the WS I get      `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate.`

Here is my configuration:

In JNLP I have defined all-permissions.

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

All jars are signed with the **same**, **self-generated** certificate.

For the first time (and if the user wants to change it) the application asks the user in a JDialog for keystore/pass and truststore/pass combination. With

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStorePath), passwordField.getPassword());
```

I check that the keystore/truststore and pass matches. If the combination matches everything is set to system properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePass);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePass);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

Then the WS is called:

```
port = new MyService(url).getMyPort();
final Map<String,Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, connection.getEndpoint());

//and here, when the app tries to authenticate to JBoss WS mechanism, I get bad_certificate exception.
port.callMethod(params);
```

From what I understand the problem is that the keystore is not loaded so then obviously the WS call fails. Can anyone explain to me why the keystore is not loaded and what am I missing?

Thank you,
Matija

Comment: I tried to build the app using signed certificate by a CA instead of self-signed to get rid of the java security warning but that didn't help. I also used another signed certificate by a CA to authenticate against the WS but keystore still doesn't load.

Does anyone know what's going wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can say that working with certs and keystores in Java is very difficult to get right! So yeah, using a CA signed cert for the app won't help with the callMethod... because the service isn't using a CA signed cert. Am I right? `callMethod` must connect to a service that has a valid cert according to Java webstart... which you've noted is not loading the keystore and I think you're right in this observation, that's how I found this question.